# What is the "correct" workflow for getting a normal map?

Tags: workflow, baking, normal-map

I am aiming to get my models that World of Warcraft stylized feel, and after a few not so great baking of normal maps, I feel like I am missing something.

Here is my current workflow:

- Model a low poly object
- Use Bevel modifier
- Use Multires modifier (add geometry manually if needed)
- UV unwrap
- Sculpt some dents, edges...
- Bake my normal

I make the texture 2048x2048, 32-bit float, non-colour, use normal map node, try adjusting max ray distance or put level viewport to 0 for multires...

I had bad baking with both multires and from selected to active.

My question is if this is a correct workflow, is there anything you would do differently?

Anything I should consider while modeling?

Also I did a small test comparing baking from multires and select to active. I must say results on baking from multires were bad. I spawned a basic cube, used bevel modifier and then multires modifier, only sculpted a bit. Here are the results :

Select to active:
[image: Select to active]

From multires:
[image: From multires]

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You said you had bad baking with both multires and from active, can you explain what you mean by "bad"?

Comment: Yeah sure, here is my latest example from testing https://imgur.com/a/qXktjYG

Focus only on the vulture, the rest could be my mistake of different kind

The vulture is on both sides of the coin and it bleeds through it from the other side. I tried with different max ray distance (1m, 0.1m, 0m...) and there is no change

Comment: 1m or 0.1m is too big for max ray distance. You should try .001 or something. Or may be you can share the blend file? (for the coin)